# Bootstrap in React.js - Navbar collapse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am facing the problem, when trying to use the navbar colapse button from Bootstrap, it doesn't work.

I think it has something to do with my page loading the jQuery library or something, though I don't understand. In node modules I found all bootstrap js files. I am also importing them in my index.js file.

Here is my code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';
import { Sitemap } from '../settings/Sitemap';

class NavigationComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container">
                    <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">Fit Vision</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggler" aria-controls="toggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggler">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            {Sitemap.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li className="nav-item" key={index}>
                                        <a className="nav-link" href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })}
                        </ul>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}>Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default NavigationComponent;
```

My index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are importing Bootstrap JS? 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' maybe?

Comment: make a working example so that anyone can understand better, you can use codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you have some classes that should be converted into className.
Second, you should know that bootstrap depends on jquery.
Please `npm install jquery` in the directory.

Now looking at the index.js file you should next files imported :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
```

Your Navigation.js should look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';
import { Sitemap } from '../settings/Sitemap';

class NavigationComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container">
                    <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">Fit Vision</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggler" aria-controls="toggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggler">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            {Sitemap.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li className="nav-item" key={index}>
                                        <a className="nav-link" href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })}
                        </ul>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}>Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default NavigationComponent;
```

Also i would suggest to use function components , it should be a simple change :

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';
import { Sitemap } from '../settings/Sitemap';

function NavigationComponent()  {
        return(
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container">
                    <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">Fit Vision</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggler" aria-controls="toggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggler">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            {Sitemap.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li className="nav-item" key={index}>
                                        <a className="nav-link" href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })}
                        </ul>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}>Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
export default NavigationComponent;
```